# How to pass ngModel to children component in Angular 9+

Tags: angular

Let's say I am using a third party component called "cal":

```
<cal [(ngModel)]="myDate" (ngModelChange)="onDateChange()"/>
```

Now I want to wrap this component inside my own component to add some feature....

```
<myComp [(ngModel)]="myDate"  (ngModelChange)="onDateChange()"/>
```

How can I implement my "myComp" component to pass myDate date to the child component?
I read some article on using ControlValueAccessor, but it always seems to be over-complicated....
I tried one of the code example, but the result was only a one way binding (from the children component to mine, but not hte other way)

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass it like that. The question is if you really need it? If you provide a little more information of what you are trying to achieve I might be able to suggest a different approach.

The ngModel works a specific way and thats why you need to implement the ControlValueAccessor interface in order to allow a custom component to act as a `Form Control`. The ngModel creates a form control and registers it with the Form element (Form Group) plus it collects all the validators connected to this control and runs all the validators whenever there is a change. It also controls the state of the control and reflects it inside the Form element (Form Group). This is why it's a bit complicated to create a custom component that acts as a form control but it's understandable and it can't be done otherwise.

If you are 100% sure that you need it for your component then you will need to implement the interface.

Actually ControlValueAccessor is not very complicated, it can be a bit confusing at times but once you implement it you will understand it so I suggest that you read the [docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) and give it a go.

I'm sure that there are many other examples on the internet but [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-custom-form-control) is one that explains how to implement it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes I am 100% sure that I need to do that. Maybe 99%... If you want to know, I am using the calendar component from PrimeNg. In my application I need to use it a lot with always the same options and always with the same custom template. So instead of copy-pasting the component usage with all the options and the custom template everywhere I need it, I was thinking about wrapping it in my own component where I will only need to pass the ngModel.
Maybe another solution would be to extend the component? I never did that.....

Comment: @tleveque have you thought about writing a `directive` that you put on the calendar component. The directive will  inject the calendar component using the `DI` and set all the properties inside? I think that this would be much easier than implementing the ControlValueAccessor and this way you can still use the `ngModel` since you don't have to wrap the calendar component. All the inputs and outputs of the component will be available inside the directive. It would also be more declarative approach since you will be using it inside the template than the imperative way of extending.

Answer (score 0):

It was finally easier than I tought to use ControlValueAccessor to acheive want I wanted. Here is my code:

DsancCalendarComponent:

```
import {Component, forwardRef, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Constants} from '../../constants';
import {DateSicService} from '../../../core/services/date-sic.service';
import {ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'dsanc-calendar',
  template: <p-calendar [id]="id" dateFormat="yy-mm-dd" placeholder="aaaa-mm-jj"
        appendTo="body" [locale]="CalendrierLocalise"
        [inputStyle]="{'width': '7em'}"
        [keepInvalid]="true"
        [defaultDate]="dateDuJour"
        [(ngModel)]="theDate" (ngModelChange)="onModelChange()"
        [showIcon]="true" [showOnFocus]="false"
        [inputId]="inputId"
        [monthNavigator]="true" [yearNavigator]="true" [yearRange]="yearRange">

        <ng-template pTemplate="date" let-date>
          <span [ngClass]="{'date-sic': (date.day === dateSic.getDate() && date.month  ===  dateSic.getMonth() && date.year === dateSic.getFullYear())}" >{{date.day}} 
          </span>
        </ng-template>
      </p-calendar>
  styleUrls: ['./dsanc-calendar.component.less'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => DsancCalendarComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class DsancCalendarComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  CalendrierLocalise: any;
  yearRange: string;
  dateSic: Date;
  dateDuJour: Date;

  @Input() id: string;
  @Input() inputId: string;

  theDate: Date;

  constructor(private dateSicService: DateSicService) {

    this.CalendrierLocalise = Constants.FR_CALENDAR;
    this.dateDuJour = this.dateSicService.getDateDuJour();
    this.dateSic = this.dateSicService.getDateSic();
    const now = new Date();
    this.yearRange = `${now.getFullYear() - 5}:${now.getFullYear() + 15}`;
  }

  // Allow the input to be disabled.
  @Input() disabled = false;

  // Function to call when the date changes.
  // noinspection JSUnusedLocalSymbols
  onChange = (theDate: Date) => {};

  // Function to call when the input is touched.
  onTouched = () => {};

  get value(): Date{
    return this.theDate;
  }

  // Allows Angular to update the model.
  // Update the model and changes needed for the view here.
  writeValue(theDate: Date): void {
    this.theDate = theDate;
    this.onChange(this.theDate);
  }

  // Allows Angular to register a function to call when the model changes.
  // Save the function as a property to call later here.
  registerOnChange(fn: (theDate: Date) => void): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  // Allows Angular to register a function to call when the input has been touched.
  // Save the function as a property to call later here.
  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  // Allows Angular to disable the input.
  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.disabled = isDisabled;
  }

  onModelChange(): void {
    this.onChange(this.theDate);
  }
}
```

And my template to use it:

```
...
<dsanc-calendar [id]="'frais_interbancaires-calendar-dateMev'" [inputId]="'frais_interbancaires-input-dateMev'"
                      [ngClass]="{'invalid-date': invalidDate}"
                      [(ngModel)]="fraisInterbancaires.dateAVenir" (ngModelChange)="onDateMevChange()"></dsanc-calendar>
...
```